# Different validation accuracy when use keras funciton fit_generator() and do prediction on every individual picture?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

Recently, I use keras to train a network to classify pictures, and use the keras function model.fit_generator() to fit my model. The fit_generator() will automatically run the model in validation data and return a validation accuracy when finish a epoch.

But odd thing happened, when I used the model to predict the validation data and compared the results with the correct class, the validation accuracy is lower than what I get when use the fit_generator().

I have two assumptions:
1. I use a generator to get data from dictionary, so I assume in one single epoch, the generator may repeatedly fetch data which is highly fitted to the model, so that the accuracy may be higher.
2. keras may use some tricks or preprocess the data when do validation, thus enhance the accuracy.

I tried to look through the source code and document of keras, but nothing helped. I would be very thankful if anyone could give me some advice about the problem.

Comment: have you tried using model.evaluate_generator to make sure you are computing accuracy correctly? Also, remember that this is a programming site, so some source code would be useful.

Comment: Are you using ImageDataGenerator with augmentation? If so, random transformations will be applied to your validation set, so variance on accuracy is  expected.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, I tried to use  model.evaluate_generator, and the result is the same as model.fit_generator

Comment: @FábioPerez No , I did't use it with any augmentation, actually, the accuracy is a constant when I use the same trained model to predict my validation data.